# Is parameterized remote trigger plugin Pipeline script(Groovy) supported?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameterized

I have two Jobs Each on running on Different Hosts Both Are Masters. which i want trigger B job After A successfully completed its Build. how can we setup Groovy Pipelines. But cant not do it with a plugin option.is Parameterized remote trigger plugin Pipeline supported? Please give detailed answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about just giving it a try? You want a detailed answer, but don't show any effort.

Comment: @StePhenKing.  Thanks for the Reply. Found  A way to do that. we can create a two local jobs which first is groovy second one is Normal Pipeline with plugin Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin. We can trigger First Job to second. The second will trigger the Remote  Job on other Jenkins.